# Accessing non-existent property 'lineno' of module exports inside circular dependency in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have a angualr project and using the vex template.

i using the the angular 9 and nodejs v15.2.0 in my project .

every time i run the project with this command `ng serve -o` it show me this warning .

[image]

**whats the problem ? how can i sovle this problem ? that error mean i use the curclur component ?**

Answer (score 0):

**tldr; upgrade from Angular 9.**

Having spent several hours on this myself, I unfortunately think it's simply a problem with the Angular 9 environment. I'm assuming it's fixed in 10+ but haven't spent time to check.

More specifically, it seems to be an issue in the `Stylus@^0.54.7` dependency that `@angular-devkit/build-angular` + `.../ng-packagr` has. You can see this if you run

`NODE_OPTIONS="--trace-warnings" npm run start`

```
...
 at new Boolean (/PATH/TO/PROJECT/node_modules/stylus/lib/nodes/boolean.js:23:8)
...
```